# Error validating install location: Distro 'centos7' does not exist in our dictionary || Host OS CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kvm

I have a very basic knowledge on Linux, and I'm working on a CentOS7 system. Now I'm tyring to configure a KVM CentOS VM, by using the `virt-install` tool. Here it is the command I wrote:

```
virt-install --name=tester1.example.com \
--ram=1024 --vcpus=2 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/tester1.example.com.img,size=16 \
--graphics=spice \
--location=ftp://127.0.0.1/pub/inst \
--os-type=linux \
--os-variant=centos7
```

and here is the error message I got:

```
Error validating install location: Distro 'centos7' does not exist in our dictionary
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, on how to get around the problem?

Comment: Yes, the error returned was merely due to a typo; then there's no way to reword the question to make it useful to others. Thank you for the explanation you wrote above. I'll try to be much more careful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I've found a workaround: I just substituted the parameter `centos7` with `centos7.0`.